# ¿Como puedo hacer saltos de linea despues de cambiar el número y después de 10 romaneos o "," en C#?

Tags: c#, .net, script

Tengo mi texto de Romaneo así:

[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]

Quiero dar saltos de línea cada 10 romaneos y cada que cambie de numero ejemplo:

EjemploLinea1->  4, 4, 4, 4, 4

EjemploLinea2->  20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20

EjemploLinea3--> 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20

Esté es mi código con el que sale el romaneo:

```
foreach ( DataRow drTablasCDatos in dtTablasCDatos.Rows ){
    string sRomaneo = string.Empty;
    sRomaneo = string.Empty;
    sRomaneo = "i,";
    foreach ( DataRow drTablasCDatosDetalle in dtTablasCDatosDetalle.Rows ){
        if( (drTablasCDatos["PRODUC_CODIGO_K"].ToString() == drTablasCDatosDetalle["PRODUC_CODIGO_K"].ToString()) && (drTablasCDatos["PRODUC_PESOVARIABLE"].ToString() != "SIN ORDEN COMPRA" ) )
                sRomaneo = sRomaneo + ", " + drTablasCDatosDetalle["INVCOMC_CANTIDAD"].ToString();  
                drTablasCDatos["ROMANEO"] = sRomaneo.Replace("i,,","");
    }
    drTablasCDatos["NOM_USUARIO"] = drUsuario["SYSUSR_NOMBRE"].ToString();
}
```

Comment: Hola! Recuerda que las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour).
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: da mas detalles, esplicate mejor, pon ejemplos y aclara q es un romaneo

Answer (score 0):

Hola Jesus intenta utilizando '\n' por ejemplo:

String linea = "4,4,4,4\n10,10,10,10,10,10"

te dara el resultado que esperas:

Linea 1 : 4,4,4,4
Linea 2 : 10,10,10,10,10,10

Espero te ayude saludos.